# Making an AST node the lowest descendent of a recursive rule

Tags: antlr

I am trying to make a parser rule which allows for zero or more of a token before a second rule and for which each successive token - of those which were part of the closure - is, in the AST, a child of the previous token, and the second rule is also a child of the last symbol.

easier to explain by example...

```
expression11 : ((NOT | COMPLEMENT)^)* expression12;
```

For example, given the above parser rule, if I have the expression !!x (where x is an ID), I want, in my AST, the x to be the child of the second bang operator which is the child of the first.

Desired:

```
!
  \ child
    !
      \ child
       x
```

Instead of my desired behavior, the above line produces an AST for which the second bang operator is a child of the first, but the x is a child of the first bang operator, a sibling of the second one. Obviously not what I want for a unary operator.

Encountered behavior:

```
        !
child /   \ child
    x -sib- !
```

If I add a third operator (as in "!!!x") the third one becomes a child of the second, as expected, and x remains a child of the first, sibling of the second.

I thought perhaps I could fix this by surrounding the entire operator part with parenthesis and adding another caret, such as

```
expression11 : (((NOT | COMPLEMENT)^)*)^ expression12;
```

in an effort to force expression12 to be a child of the entire closure of operators, hoping in vain that this would be interpreted as "The child of the entire closure means the child of the most-descended," but that was not the case and doing this did not change the behavior at all.

My question is "How do I get the parser to process the rule in such a way that the result of expression12 becomes the child of the most-descended 'NOT' or 'COMPLEMENT' node instead of the highest ancestor one?"

I would have thought this would be simple, but I cannot figure it out from the Antlr resources on antlr.org nor by pleading with Google. It must be done all the time, or is there a different way to structure the rule entirely which I am overlooking?

Here are the following rules for completeness. They are not finished yet and will be modified, but they are complete and working for testing and all is well with them - as expected since they are straightforward. 12 is for array length and method calls, 13 is for new classes and arrays, 14 for array indexing, and 15 for terminals/parenthesis.

```
expression12 : expression13 (DOT (LENGTH | (ID LPAREN (expression (COMMA expression)*)? RPAREN)))?;
expression13 : expression14 | (NEW^ ((ID LPAREN RPAREN) | (INTTYPE LSQBRACK expression RSQBRACK)));
expression14 : expression15 (LSQBRACK expression RSQBRACK)*;
expression15 : (LPAREN expression RPAREN) | INTLIT | TRUE | FALSE | ID | THIS;
```

Thank you to anyone who can provide assistance; your time is much appreciated.

Comment: I must say your choice of rule names is rather confusing. Besides that, a good, and detailed question! +1

Comment: @Bart Kiers: This is all part of my greater expression rule, and each expressionN rule is a different level of precedence, with expression1 being my lowest precedence operator (logical OR), and expression15 being the highest. Perhaps not the way others go about it, but I have not been doing this long and am still learning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must not use the Kleene star if you don't want operators to appear as siblings. Try something like (untested)

```
expression11 : (NOT | COMPLEMENT)^ expression11
             | expression12;
```

Comment: After using your answer, I finally found the answer also in the antlr mailing list (http://antlr.1301665.n2.nabble.com/A-little-trouble-with-parsing-unary-operators-td5067826.html#a5067826). I thought it had to exist somewhere. Anyway, simple and works great; thank you much.